# Prevent stop launching when one of the device disconnects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start the installation on 10 devices and for example one device is disconnected during the process, the whole process stops. I would like the installation process to be completed for the remaining 9 devices. Is it possible?

App configuration
[image: App configuration]

AS version: `Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4`
I am not using any special run configuration, no plugins installed.
For install and run: `Select multiple devices` in Android Studio and tap to `Run app`

Comment: You should provide more detail (plugins, commands, scripts) as to how you are installing on 10 devices with Android Studio.

Comment: Added more information to the original post.